# Not able to update channel entries related to store, other issues

Tags: expresso-store

I’ve recently updated a site from 2.5.2 to 2.7.3. I've also updated Store from 1.6.1 to 1.6.5. I’m experiencing issues in certain sections of the back-end, namely editing channel entries and working with the Template Manager.

For one channel, when I click Submit I receive the following error:

```
Error Number: 1030

Got error 139 from storage engine

Filename: libraries/api/Api_channel_entries.php

Line Number: 1665
```

For another channel, I receive an empty click when trying to Submit or Save Revisions. Nothing is firing in console.

A third issue is, the template manager is empty. Screenshot:

[image: Empty Template Manager]

Is anyone familiar with these issues? I’ve run out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message "Got error 139 from storage engine" is being thrown by MySQL. I bet your tables are using a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM storage engine.

Check your database and confirm it's using MyISAM. If it's using InnoDB, [this question may help with converting it to MyISAM using phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280754/mysql-convert-innodb-to-myisam-storage-engine-of-database).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Seems the fix isn't this simple but it's a start. And yes, there is definitely a combination of the two in the database.